# Using Glide for Android, what's a good way to use (local) alternative sources for urls?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images in my Android app:

Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://www.example.com/whatever/icon.png")
    .into(imageView);

I would like to bundle some images in my app APK file to make sure that they are always available even if the device is offline. I would still like to use Glide to benefit from features such as memory caching of resized images, loading and scaling in a background thread and also to keep the interface for displaying images consistent.

Each image that I need to load like this is specified by a URL. 
If there's a local version ( the local file name is generated by using a part of the URL [ e.g. replacing  "http://www.example.com/" with "file:///android_asset/bundled_images/whatever/" ] in the URL string ), I would like to use that one. If not, the image needs to be downloaded from the actual URL.

Here's an example:

I have an image at http://www.example.com/whatever/icon.png
I will bundle this image in the apk under:

/assets/bundled_images/whatever/icon.png

The rule would be as follows:

If the image file exists under local assets, use that file. If the image does not exist under local assets, use the remote file.

Whenever I request an image to be loaded into an imageview, I would like to be able to use just the full URL (http://www.example.com/whatever/icon.png), and my image loader should automatically be able to check for a local copy first.

Can I do something like this with any of Glide's functionality? Yes, I could of course to the file exists check before calling glide, but it seems like a common enough use case that Glide could/should have a feature for this. Would also be nice to do the file-exists check in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve required flexibility by adding custom `GlideModule` in the way described here: [Glide Configuration](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration). Also you need to implement appropriate Glide's Loader which would encapsulate the logic for downloading. In your case it can be something similar to [UriLoader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/UriLoader.java).

Answer (score 1):

Glide provides an option to load a local image if the device is offline.
This can be done using the **error()** method.

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl)
                .error(localImageResId)
                .into(mIconView);
```

The code above downloads an image from imageUrl and loads it into the imageView.
In case of an error (ex device offline) it loads the local image resourse.